# Reveal Hidden Elements with Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row made of three buttons, and I need these three buttons to remain on the same row.

With that said, I am trying to make it so that each time one of these buttons is clicked, hidden content is displayed underneath them. Each button would show hidden content that is different from the other.

Is there anyway I can accomplish such a task using `$(this)` or must I assign a unique ID to each button and the relevant content it's supposed to show?

I have tried placing each button within a superclass called `.items` and the relevant content within this class as a child, called `.description`--so that I can access it using jQuery's `.children()` function--but this tends to mess up the row that my buttons are on (so that they are not all on the same row). Is there anyway to get around this?

What would be the simplest way to go about this?

Edit to show code:

```
<div class="displayers">
    <div class="items">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom">Button 1</button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="description">
                <p> content here </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom">Button 2</button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="description">
                <p> content here </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom">Button 3</button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="description">
                <p> content here </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to make the buttons fit on the same row, I changed the ".items" class to have the property of "inline-block". The ".description" class is hidden, and I have some jQuery to reveal it.

```
var main = function() {
    $('.items').click(function() {
        $('.description').hide(); 

        $(this).children('.description').show();
    });
}; 

$(document).ready(main);
```

The problem with this is that my buttons are no longer on the same row.

Comment: Could you show the relevant HTML?

Comment: is it something like tabs - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs but with buttons looking like http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups ?

Comment: Yes, you have to assing a uniqe ID to every button and to the containers holding the corresponding content.

Comment: @shershen Yes, that would be okay, but the content that the btns would link to must be hidden at first.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `data` attributes and css selectors (easy to change later on), so I would use:

```js
$('[data-show]').on('click', function(e) {
    var toShow = $( $(this).data('show') );
    toShow.siblings().hide();
    toShow.show();
});
```

```css
li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <button data-show=".content > *:nth-child(1)">Open 1st</button>
    <button data-show=".content > *:nth-child(2)">Open 2nd</button>
    <button data-show=".content > *:nth-child(3)">Open 3rd</button></p> 
<ul class="content">
    <li>1st Container</li>
    <li>2nd Container</li>
    <li>3rd Container</li>
</ul>
```

Looks pretty simple to me, but does not mean others would agree. It really depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks like it is exactly what I needed. I will apply it to my code and see what happens. Is there any reason why you wrapped the buttons in p?

Comment: Not at all, just because you said they were in one line. They may be anywhere on the page.

Comment: I tried using your code, but for some reason, it's not working. Instead of using a <ul> element, I placed my ".content" class in a <div>, then I had three <divs> within my ".content" class--to ensure each <div> was a sibling. Could this be the problem? I am also using a newer version of jQuery, 2.1.4.

Comment: No, nothing from above is problem, except if you put `<div class=".content">` - class name should be **without a dot**: `<div class="content"><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>`

Comment: I recreated it in JS fiddle, it gave me the same problem there as well. https://jsfiddle.net/mattdoesit/jew8mkfv/2/

Comment: Your css is wrong, you should hide children, not content wrapper - [take a look](https://jsfiddle.net/jew8mkfv/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just `toggle` the elements which is next to your `button` with just `class` added to each element as below:

```js
$('.btnshowdes').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next('.desc').toggle();
});
```

```css
.desc{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
    <div class="internal">
        <input type="button" class="btnshowdes" value="Toggle Description"/>
        <div class="desc">Description 1</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="internal">
        <input type="button" class="btnshowdes" value="Toggle Description"/>
        <div class="desc">Description 2</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="internal">
        <input type="button" class="btnshowdes" value="Toggle Description"/>
        <div class="desc">Description 3</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="internal">
        <input type="button" class="btnshowdes" value="Toggle Description"/>
        <div class="desc">Description 4</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/znen0rux/)**

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated question to make it in the same row you just need to put an extra style to your `.items` as below:

```
.items{
    display:inline-table; //helps to keep it in same row
    padding:10px;//Just to make it feel good

}
```

Your **`js`** according to your `html` structure will be:

```
$('.btn-custom').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next('.row').find('.description').toggle();
});
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/znen0rux/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, Guruprasad! I noticed that the content gets displayed directly underneath the button--following its exact split in terms of the column size. What would you do if you wanted the content to be displayed without those restrictions? For example, let the content that gets revealed by each button have the entire row underneath the buttons... so that it occupies "col-12" and is not constrained by the content of the other two buttons when toggled.

Comment: Use `position:absolute` on contents  but I am afraid that it would `overlap` on the contents when it will have full width!!

Comment: Do you mean add position: absolute; to the ".description" class? It still seems like it is bound by its parent class, and has those restrictions on its width--as a matter of fact, if the content is too long, it collapses the buttons. Is there anyway to make it so one row is reserved for the buttons, and the second row, where the content will be displayed is free of any constraints? So it operates like a <div> tag that is not connected to the buttons? I do not mind if the content overlaps underneath the button, I only need one element to be displayed or shown at a time.

Comment: Can you create a visualization of what you expect??

Comment: But do you see how the content for "button 2" falls midway, and does not begin where a col-12 row would begin? Likewise, for button 3, the content begins toward the end and does not begin where a col-12 row would begin.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem i would split my elements. Why don't you put each button in a different container (a div for instance), each container having his own id and his own content.

So when you click on a button you display the content inside of one div and the style of other buttons will not be affected.

Something like

```
<div class="container" id="1">
    <button id="btn1"> Button one </button>
    <!-- your content here linked to the script you use to display -->
</div>
<div class="container" id="2">
    <button id="btn2"> Button two </button>
    <!-- your content here linked to the script you use to display -->
</div>
<!-- etc... -->
```

So you don't have to worry and use complicated scripts, and each style will not be affected by the others modifications.

Comment: I attempted to do that, Remy. But when I did that, placing each button within its own separate div, it gave each one of my buttons its own row. Thus, they were no longer on the same row. I tried to remedy this by giving the divs an "inline-block" property, but then the content (when it would be shown) would throw off my button arrangement as well, so that they were not all on the same row.